# Why the result in the mysql is abnormal when the emoj is included in data?

Tags: mysql, utf8mb4

enviroument : linux + node 0.10.22 + mysql 5.6.31

recently,there are some wrong result in my database.

**Normal results are json strings just like '{"content": "hello,world!", "sender":"warriorA"} '.**
**Abnormal results are json strings like  '{"content": "hello,world!" '.**

It looks like there is a part missing.I know the mysql's bug about utf8 and utf8mb4, I guess that's probably why. I confirmed in the production environment that it was emoj. but When I tried to reproduce in the testing environment, I was a little depressed.

in testing environment, the mysql give me an Error “truncated_wrong_value_for_field, Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x90\xA6,...' for column 'mailParams' at row 1”, not like online.

I don't know how to reproduce and solve this problem, may I have your advice? Thank you very much.

Comment: Use `utf8mb4`, not `utf8`, for the `CHARACTER SET` and the connection parameters.

Comment: See "truncation" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored